# index_name and _routing in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a mapping as below

```
{
   "obj" : {
      "properties": {
         "name" : {
              "type" : "string",
              "index_name" : "firstname"
         }
     },
     "_routing" : {
         "required" : "true",
         "path"  : "name"

     }
   }
}
```

Now if I upload a document like

{
   "name" : "test"
}

I am getting below error

nested: MapperParsingException[External routing [test] and document path routing [null] mismatch]

However if I remove "index_name" from the mapping I am able to upload the document. Am I missing any configuration here ? We would like to retain the index_name as it provides much more readable string to end user.

Comment: What version of elasticsearch are you using?

Comment: its elasticsearch 0.90

Comment: What if you specify `"path":"firstname"` keeping the `index_name`?

Comment: i tried that too. It didnt work.

Comment: I've the same problem and cannot find any solutions.

Comment: I checked this is 1.3.1 and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the above mapping in 1.3.1 and mapping is getting created.

Comment: dont use path, its depreciated in elasticsearch